# c - read() and fread() return values

Tags: c, io, fread

good people of SO!

I have rather a theoretical question.
At `read()` manpages i read the following:

```
   On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.  In this
   case, it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any)
   changes.
```

While in `fread()` ones the correspondend fragment is the following:

```
   If an error occurs, or the end of the file is
   reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).
   ...
   **fread()** does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and
   callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.
```

My question - is there any practical reason why `read()` do distinguish EOF and an error, and `fread()` not?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The interfaces evolved at different times and presumably by different implementors.

Comment: @tadman - i m still getting used to the fact that standard library may have things due to "just because", rather than to some mastermind`s plan.

Comment: Many of these things are design decisions that made sense at the time. When C came about in 1972 computers had extremely limited resources, like *kilobytes* of memory was considered luxurious and a *megabyte* of memory was still out of reach. As later computers added more capability, things like buffered reads via `fread` made sense, but this was long after `read` was already laid down.

Comment: @tadman - so, are you saying that the input actually read by `fread()` was whey too precious (due to limited resources) to just discard on error and simply return -1?

Comment: I think Barmar has a good explanation for the technical details of "why", but on a more general level you need to keep in mind that not every function is going to work as you'd expect on a modern computer with gigabytes of memory and gigahertz speed CPUs. In an age of kilobytes and kilohertz you had to be extremely efficient. In the case of `fread()`, as with many things, if you wanted to know more you had to ask. Doing extra work that's never used is really wasteful and had to be avoided.

Comment: You can see different styles of argument passing and result code formatting being used throughout C and its associated libraries. The differences are subtle but reflect the thinking at the time. This has been locked in since C is really averse to changing things that could break older code.

Comment: @tadman - yeah, from a technical point of view it is clear now. I guess on a more general level it is just something to accept as is. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `fread` is `size_t`. This is an unsigned type, so there's no available value that would be different from a value indicating how many items were read.

Furthermore, `fread()` may need to call `read()` multiple times to read all the items that were requested. If an error or EOF occurs on one of the later reads, it should still return all the items that were successfully read before that. So it returns that item count.

Since the reason for the short item count can't be encoded in the return value, it would need to have some other way of returning this. It's easier to just leave that to the caller, using `feof()` and `ferror()`.

If `read()` encounters an error after a partial read, this is usually treated as success. It returns the length of the data that was read. The caller doesn't find out about the error until the *next* call to `read()`, when it returns `-1` and sets `errno`.

A signal can also cause `read()` to return early. In this case it returns `-1` and sets `errno == EINTR`. The kernel keeps the partial read in a buffer so it can be returned on the next call.

Comment: But why then `read()` doesn't return number of bytes successfully read if error occurs? I mean, i do understand that it is a basic single call to the system, but if `read()` doesn't do it, why `fread()` should? Is it any more useful in practice?

Comment: Because it doesn't have any way of reporting an error other than by returning a negative value.

Comment: @AntonTretyakov: While a great deal of flexibility is allowed for how implementations treat errors, in principle *it does*. `read` can return a short read, and one of the reasons it does is encountering a reason it can't continue after a partial read has already taken place. For example this is mandatory with end-of-file condition and `EINTR` (if you have interrupting signal handlers installed), but I think it would be the preferred behavior for all errors, and most implementations probably do it that way. After all, you'll see the reason you can't go on when you attempt to continue.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Thanks, I've updated the answer to explain my understanding of those situations.

Comment: read can't fail with EINTR after already transferring data. Then the amount transferred would be lost. Instead it *succeeds* with a short read. EINTR can only happen if no data was transferred.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE That's what I said, the pending data is buffered so the next read will get it.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE ahh, this is a delicate nuance! Thank you guys, now it is more clear for me.